# Efficient way for multiple 2 value true false if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have an if else statements that has 2 values that need to be evaluated whether they're null or not, then based on that, it chooses the right statement. The code below:

```
int? x;
int? y;

if(x == null and y == null) { do this part; }
else if (x != null and y == null) {do this second part; }
else if (x == null and y != null) {do this third part; }
else { do this last part; }
```

I am trying to find if there is a more efficient way to implement this. There is the option of a case statement, but I still want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: No reason to check for `x != null` or `y != null` in those second and third conditions. If it made it that far in the logic, then only a check for `y = null` and `x = null` is necessary.

Comment: Why should an int ever be null? Init it with 0.

Comment: @MarkusZeller thank for pointing it out, i just modified it to be nullable

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: As others have noted, you could nest your `if` statements; however, if we know more about what the "parts" are that you are trying to execute, we might be able to advise further; C# has many features that allow you to concisely express "lifted to nullable" semantics without writing `if` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a nested `if`, so each variable is only evaluated once, instead of multiple times as suggested in the OP snippet.

```
if (x == null) {
    if (y == null) {
        // Both are null
    } else {
        // Only x is null
    }
} else {
    if (y == null) {
        // Only y is null
    } else {
        // Neither are null
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add more details/elaborate on your solution as to *why* you would use a nested `if`, this would bring more value to your solution and would help the OP understand.

Comment: @Mureinik thanks a lot for your response. Would this be faster than a switch statement?